# Overheating laptop with Ubuntu 16..04. Should I try Xubuntu?

Tags: drivers, graphics, xubuntu, amd-graphics, overheating

If Xubuntu would be a good option to reduce overheating and loud fan on my laptop even though it's performances are pretty solid, I need you to confirm it and probably I'll give it a shot.

HP Pavilion DV7:

i7 gen2 2.0 GHZ (quad core)
8gb ram
1.5TB HDD
6GB graphics:
-AMD RADEON [HD 6000M Series (2GB)]
-Intel HD Graphics (4GB)

Also, I should mention that I've tried to stop the AMD discrete graphic card, but it didnt seem to do the job.

Your help and opinions are highly appreciated!

Comment: Try to install `lm-sensors` then run `sensors` and give us the result.

Comment: Install `cpufrequtils` and run `cpufreq-info`.

Comment: Here is the result from running sensors

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +41.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +36.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +35.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +37.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +37.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +38.0°C  (crit = +99.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:            N/A  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)

Comment: the result of cpufreq-info is way too long and I cant seem to paste it on a formatted way

Comment: You could paste it in the question and between \`\`\` like \`\`\`code\`\`\`

Comment: i did it, not the formatted way tho, hope u can help

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that overheating is not due ubuntu 16.04. Maybe this could help:

https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/108083/Laptop+shuts+off+from+overheating

Comment: Thank you weatherman but I tried before what the first answer said to do, it didn't quite help.

Answer (score 0):

As per my observation, gnome consumes a bit of processor even when idle. Since unity is also based on gnome, it too has the same problem. This causes the so called overheating problem and fan noise especially in laptops with graphics card.

I too have an ATI graphics card in my sony vaio laptop and when I tried any gnome based linux, it showed the same problem. Therefore I have installed xubuntu and it shows no overheating problem since then.

So, my conclusion is: you can confidently go forward with installing Xubuntu in your system.

P.S. Xubuntu has some page tearing problem. For ATI graphics one can correct this by enabling `TearFree` in the `xorg.conf` file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Subham! I am definately gonna give it a try.